# How to manually develop a UUID without using uuidgen?

Tags: linux, shell-script

For an assessment we have been asked to generate two different versions of UUID without the use of built-in UUID generators, I can't find any information on how to do that, i only know `uuidgen` and cant figure out how to make my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Build-in methods

Checkout the following guide on UUID generation in bash:

- https://www.baeldung.com/linux/bash-generate-uuid

Despite `uuidgen` it features the following methods:

- kernel generator: `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`
- python: `python –c “import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())”`

### Pure bash implementation

https://serverfault.com/a/597626

If you decide to implement it yourself, remember to check if it is correct
according to standard RFC 4122: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122

### Similar question with other ideas

https://serverfault.com/questions/103359/how-to-create-a-uuid-in-bash